# Is there a model structure for inner fibrations over $S$?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, higher-category-theory, model-categories

$
\def\Set{\operatorname{Set}}
\def\fP{\mathfrak{P}}
\def\deg{\operatorname{deg}}
$
Let $S \in \Set_{\Delta}$. Does there exist a model structure ( - which would be uniquely determined - ) on the category $(\Set_{\Delta})_{/S}$ having the following properties?:

- The cofibrations are the monomorphisms.
- An object $(X, p : X \to S)$ is fibrant if and only if $p$ is an inner fibration.

If it exists, it might be called the *model category for inner fibrations over $S$* or the *model category for correspondences over $S$*.

The locally (co)Cartesian model category $(\Set_{\Delta}^+)_{/\fP}$ over the categorical pattern $\fP := (\deg_1(S),\deg_2(S),\emptyset)$ over $S$ comes pretty close and seems to me to be a marked version of what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Proposition.** Let $S \in \operatorname{Set}_{\Delta}$. There exists a Cisinski model structure on the category $(\operatorname{Set}_{\Delta})_{/S}$ having as fibrant objects precisely those objects $(X,p : X \to S)$ such that $p$ is an inner fibration.
>
> **Proof.** The wanted model structure on $(\operatorname{Set}_{\Delta})_{/S}$ is left-induced from the locally (co)Cartesian model structure on $(\Set_{\Delta}^+)_{/\fP} = (\operatorname{Set}_{\Delta}^+)_{/S^{\flat}}$ with respect to the categorical pattern $\fP := (\deg_1(S),\deg_2(S),\emptyset)$ over $S$ via the functor $\cdot^{\flat} : (\operatorname{Set}_{\Delta})_{/S} \to (\operatorname{Set}_{\Delta}^+)_{/S^{\flat}}$. $\ \blacksquare$
>
> **Remark.** For the notion of a *left-induced model structure* see the paper [*A necessary and sufficient condition for induced model structures*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.08154) by Hess, Kędziorek, Riehl, Shipley.